# Open App Store if app isn't installed IOS 2021

Tags: javascript, ios, deep-linking, ios-universal-links

I'm trying to get IOS recognize if my app is not installed when i click in a button on my web. I have everthing that says IOS, apple-app-site-association, in our app everything is set to that, and when the app is already installed, it works! But, if the app is not installed, safary returns an incorrect message, and freeze the next code (i tried to apply the settimeout to do a redirect to the appstore)

I saw multiple cases here on stackoverflow, but none works now...

Answer (score 0):

I think this is an unsolvable problem with plain html and javascript. iOS will always show an error popup if you click an app-link but don't have the app installed. I've seen many production sites that suffer from the issue too, like medium.com

I've also tried the famous `setTimeout`-hack to open AppStore a few seconds later if the user remains on the page but didn't quite get it to work at all (or without causing other issues like freezes)

The one hope for a solution is that a colleague told me about a Firebase SDK solution that promises they'll handle this for you

> set up the links that will move people from your website into your native app. Don't worry if your users don't have the app installed yet; Dynamic Links can take care of that for you.
> https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/use-cases/web-to-app

I haven't tried it out yet though.

Comment: Thanks for anwsering! I think you're right. Firebase Links is one of the best solutions so far. 
I would liked to know how firebase does this.

Comment: I've tried it out now. Works great on most browsers. Just a little caveat though is Incognito Modes. Seems it cannot detect if you have the app installed when running certain Incognito modes. iOS + Safari Incognito works. But for other Incognito browsers on iOS you'll see Firebase will, even if it opens the installed app, also ALWAYS trigger the fallback link intended for those who don't have the app installed. Same with Android + Chrome Inconito: when the app is opened, the fallback link is also triggered at the same time. Bit ugly but no biggie.